# android - using firestore instead of auth

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to make an android app that has users and everything related to it.
I just want to know if it is possible to use Firebase Firestore instead of Firebase Auth and if yes, how can I do that.

Any example would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know if it is possible to use Firebase Firestore
>   instead of Firebase Auth

I'm assuming that you're asking to use **Firebase Firestore** instead of **Firebase realtime database** with **Firebase Auth** which is the current and stable version for that.

**From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/):**

> Cloud Firestore is a flexible, scalable database for mobile, web, and
>   server development from Firebase and Google Cloud Platform. *Like
>   Firebase Realtime Database*, ***it keeps your data in sync across client
>   apps through realtime listeners and offers offline support for mobile
>   and web so you can build responsive apps that work regardless of
>   network latency or Internet connectivity***. Cloud Firestore also offers
>   seamless integration with other Firebase and Google Cloud Platform
>   products, including Cloud Functions.

It's actually in **beta release** but you can use it.

Start using it with this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

And the available sample: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/firestore